# System Header and normal header gcc

Tags: c, gcc, header, operating-system, header-files

I know it is a very stupid question but I cannot get the difference between system header and normal header in gcc.

Refering to this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html):

> 2.8 System Headers
>
> The header files declaring interfaces to the operating system and
>   runtime libraries often cannot be written in strictly conforming C.
>   Therefore, **GCC gives code found in system headers special treatment**.
>   All warnings, other than those generated by ‘#warning’ (see
>   Diagnostics), are suppressed while GCC is processing a system header.
>   Macros defined in a system header are immune to a few warnings
>   wherever they are expanded. This immunity is granted on an ad-hoc
>   basis, when we find that a warning generates lots of false positives
>   because of code in macros defined in system headers.
>
> Normally, only the headers found in specific directories are
>   considered system headers. These directories are determined when GCC
>   is compiled. There are, however, **two ways to make normal headers into
>   system headers:**
>
> Header files found in directories added to the search path with the -isystem and -idirafter command-line options are treated as system
>   headers for the purposes of diagnostics.
>       There is also a directive, #pragma GCC system_header, which tells GCC to consider the rest of the current include file a system header,
>   no matter where it was found. Code that comes before the ‘#pragma’ in
>   the file is not affected. #pragma GCC system_header has no effect in
>   the primary source file.

I appreciate an answer showing some contents of system header if possible and what kind of warnings or special treatment is talking about in the link.

Answer (score 1):

System headers are header files that come with the OS or compiler, and are located in directories like `/usr/include` on Unix. Normal headers are everything else, such as the header files you write yourself, or files that come with an application or library you download.

Comment: So you mean system headers are headers in default paths of Gcc compilers.

Comment: The documentation you quoted says "specific directories". I don't know if it's the same as all the default directories, it might just be some of them.

Comment: @Bramar: The link says: ` These directories are determined when GCC is compiled.`  This means that if you compile GCC from source yourself, then you determine what these directories are.

Comment: You could, by editing the appropriate GCC source file that lists them.

Answer (score 1):

`what kind of warnings or special treatment is talking about in the link.`

These are warnings that are issued for C usage that is deprecated under current standards but was considered acceptable when the system headers were written.  For example, the warning `you are assigning a string literal to a char*"`. (which nowadays would be done using the `const` keyword).